# UWP Template 10 Hamburger Menu. Update button text programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, hamburger-menu, template10

I have an application that will support multiple languages. Each language is held in a ResourceDictionary which is then merged into the main resource dictionary at run-time. Every thing works find except for the Hamburger menu. The menu never displays the merged values from the dictionary. Each button in the menu has its text bound to a StaticResource.

The Hamburger menu even seems to be created before OnInitializeAsync is called in the App.xmal.cs because this is where I merge the dictionaries and the Hamburger menu always loads the default text from the main dictionary.

In the application when I select a different language the rest on the application changes immediately to the new language but the Hamburger menu never updates the text, and I cannot find any way to force it to update the text.

Does anybody know how to dynamically change the text on the buttons in the Hamburger menu?

Comment: I solved the problem of getting the menu text to change when the programs start up. I do the dictionary merge as the very first thing in OnInitializeAsync before any thing else has executed. But I'm still unable to get the menu to change once the app is running.

Comment: We would be more usefull if you provide us with a sample application.

Answer (score 0):

This is particularly simple. Remember, this is just XAML. Inside your HamburgerButtonInfo you provide the TextBlock with the text you have. All you need to do is add an x:Name to that TextBlock and you can change it however you want from within Shell. I am not sure this makes sense, but I sure hope it does. Remember, this is just updating a TextBlock, not updating something with Template 10. Remember, this is just XAML.

```
public class Shell
{
    public void UpdateText(string text)
    {
        this.MyTextBlock.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Nothing special.

Comment: As I'm changing the dictionary to which all the button are bound, is there no way to get the hamburger menu to refresh all it's contents automatically? Your implying that I have to iterate through all the buttons, find each button's text inside the xaml and then do a manual dictionary lookup to change the text. Normally I can call NavigationService.Refresh() and everything updates.